# Updating Global Managed Navigation

Tags: powershell, managed-navigation

Consider the following PowerShell script to update a Term Set 'Global Navigation' which is pinned throughout the farm:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea SilentlyContinue

Write-Host "Updating Global Navigation for the entire farm"
$url = 'http://spserver:2013'
$termStoreName = 'Managed Metadata Service'
$termGlobalGroupName = 'Global Navigation'
$termSetName = 'Global Navigation'

function Get-NavStore() {
    $web = Get-SPWeb $url
    $site = $web.Site
    $taxSession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $site
    return $taxSession.TermStores[$termStoreName]
}

function Get-NavTerms() {
    $termStore = Get-NavStore
    $termGroup = $termStore.Groups[$termGlobalGroupName]
    $termSet = $termGroup.TermSets[$termSetName]
    return $termSet.Terms
}

foreach ($site in Get-SPSite -Limit all) {
    $navTerms = Get-NavTerms
    $taxSession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $site
    $termStore = $taxSession.TermStores[$termStoreName]
    $name = "Site Collection - " + $site.HostName + $site.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace('/','-').TrimEnd('-')
    $termGroup = $termStore.Groups | ? {$_.Name -eq $name}
    if ($termGroup.Count -lt 1) {
        Write-Host "Skipping:" $site.Url "(No group found matching '$name')"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Found group:" $termGroup.Name
        $termSets = $termGroup.TermSets | ? {$_.Name -match "Navigation"}
        if ($termSets.Count -lt 1) {
            Write-Host "No term sets found with the name 'Navigation'"
        } elseif ($termSets.Count -gt 1) {
            Write-Host "Too many term sets found with the name 'Navigation'"
        } else {
            $termSet = $termSets[0]
            $terms = $termSet.Terms
            foreach ($t in $terms) {
                Write-Host "Deleting" $t.Name
                $t.Delete()
            }
            $termStore.CommitAll()

            foreach ($t in $navTerms) {
                Write-Host "Pinning" $t.Name
                $termSet.ReuseTermWithPinning($t) | out-null
            }
            $termSet.CustomSortOrder = $termSet.CustomSortOrder
            $termStore.CommitAll()
        }
    }
}
```

This script works, however I have to run it twice. This is because the first time it runs through I receive the following error when trying to `ReuseTermWithPinning`:

```
Exception calling "ReuseTermWithPinning" with "1" argument(s): "Terms can not be shared multiple times in the same term set"
At line:49 char:17
+                 $termSet.ReuseTermWithPinning($t) | out-null
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TermStoreOperationException
```

I run it again, and I do not get this error as it doesn't need to Delete any nodes -- simply Reuse them. Its as if when I run the `.CommitAll()` it does not actually commit the changes and I'm trying to pin terms that are still there. It only commits the data when exiting out of the script. I have tried to break out the logic differently and have tried to reload the Managed Metadata objects but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would provide an update on how I achieved a better overall solution. I took the same logic within the PowerShell script and created a custom Visual Studio solution that has an application page with a button that syncs the terms and outputs a report.

The only other issue I ran into with that was with the hidden Taxonomy feature not being activated on team sites.